# How to implement background processing for ASP.Net MVC website in a shared hosting environment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, background-process

I am developing my first web application using ASP.Net MVC, and I am in a situation where I would like a background service to process status notifications outside of the application, not unlike the reputation/badge system on stackoverflow.

What is the best way to handle something like this? Is it even possible in a shared-hosting environment like Godaddy, which I am using.

I don't need to communicate with the background worker directly, since I will be adding notification records to a database table with a column set to an "unprocessed" state. Then the worker will just scan the table on a regular schedule and processes what is ready.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the background job ? Does it take long? is it cpu intensive? What are the main reasons why you can't you run it along with the request?

Comment: Sure. The background job will process payment status notifications that come in asynchronously from Paypal. Depending on the status, the job will perform different database operations. It is not too intensive, and currently I do process it within the application. But it seemed to be a better design to just log the information in a table at the time of receipt and have the background worker process it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried with [quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net)? I think it may fit your needs.

Comment: Okay, just so I understand, if I run a quartz job from the global.asax, that would ensure it running as long as the website was running? Because that would be exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes! you set it up on the application_start.

Comment: unfortunately Godaddy applies medium trust on IIS, this restricts the use of quartz

Answer (score 5):

also take a look at this [Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx) article.

it explains a nice way to schedule operations with no outer dependence.

The idea is to use Cache timeout to control the schedule. I've implemented it successfully on a project which required regular temp file cleaning. This cleaning is a bit heavy so we move this clean operation in a scheduled job (using the asp.net cache) to avoid having to deploy scheduled task or custom program.

Comment: Excellent technique! Looks like this was actually used on StackOverflow.com. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/.

Answer (score 3):

To answer whether GoDaddy will support a seperate service you need to ask them.

However there are a number of creative ways that you can "get around" this issue on shared hosting.

1. Have a secure page that's purpose is to execute your background work. You could have scheduled task on a machine under your control that calls to this web page at set intervals.
2. Use a variation of the Background Worker Thread answer from @safi. Your background worker thread could check to see if another is already processing and stop, so that only one instance is running at a time.

Comment: #1 is what I'd go for. Some hosting providers like DiscountASP even let you specify a URL that their server polls at a predefined interval, essentially to let you implement #1

Comment: A variant of #1 would be a secure, light REST service. Maybe a simple `JsonResult` method, called by a client (that calls it from time to time). Basically the same idea, done in a slightly more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

If only one background task is enough for you then use the [WebBackgrounder](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder)
And this is the [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) with detailed explanation.