# Taking the OOP Plunge

Tags: php

I decided to start or try to start coding in OOP for my PHP apps.  here is my first class.  the intention of this class is to start a form and build the different elements.  please let me know if it is even in the right track.  The fields are already stored in the database. the priority param is not doing anything yet, but will highlight the question.

```
//Form Class
<?php

class form {

        function genQuestion ($id) {

        $type = $this->getQuestionType($id);

        $priority = $this->getQuestionPriority($id);

        if ($field['type'] == "text") {
            $html .= $this->add_text_field($id, $priority);
        }
        if ($field['type'] == "select") {
            $html .= $this->add_select_field($id, $priority);
        }
        if ($this->type == 'radio') {
            $html .= $this->add_radio_field($id, $priority);
        }
        if ($field['type'] == "checkbox") {
            $html .= $this->add_checkbox_field($id, $priority);
        }       

        return $html;

    }

    function getQuestionType ($id) {
        $field_query = "SELECT type FROM fields WHERE id = '$id'";
        $field = mysql_query($field_query);
        $field = mysql_fetch_assoc($field);
        $this->type = $field['type'];       
    }   

    function getQuestionPriority ($id) {
        $field_query = "SELECT priority FROM fields WHERE id = '$id'";
        $field = mysql_query($field_query);
        $field = mysql_fetch_assoc($field);
        $this->type = $field['priority'];       
    }       

    function add_text_field($id) {
        $fields_query = "SELECT * FROM fields WHERE id = '$id'";
        $fields = mysql_query($fields_query);
        $field = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields); 
        $content .= '<div><label> ' . $field['field'] . ': </label>';       
        $content .= '<input type="text" name="' . $field['id'] . '"></div>';
        return $content;
    } 

    function add_select_field($id) {
        $fields_query = "SELECT * FROM fields WHERE id = '$id'";
        $fields = mysql_query($fields_query);
        $field = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields); 
        $content .= '<div><label> ' . $field['field'] . ': </label>';       
        $options = explode('|', $field['options']);
        $content .= '<select name="' . $field['id'] . '">'; 
        while (list($key, $value) = each($labels)) {
            $content .= '<option value="' . $key . '"> ' .  $value . '</option>';
        }
        $content .= '</select></div>';
        return $content;
    } 

    function add_radio_field($id) {
        $fields_query = "SELECT * FROM fields WHERE id = '$id'";
        $fields = mysql_query($fields_query);
        $field = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields); 
        $content .= '<div style="float: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; text-align: right; clear: both;"><div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-right: 25px;"><label> ' . $field['field'] . ': </label></div>';      
        $options = explode('|', $field['options']);
        while (list($key, $value) = each($options)) {
            $content .= '<div style="float: left; margin-right: 7px;">' . $value . '</div><div style="float: left;  margin-right: 17px;"><input type="radio" name="' . $field['id'] . '" value="' . $key . '" /></div>';
        }
        $content .= '</div>';
        return $content;
    } 

    function add_checkbox_field($id) {
        $fields_query = "SELECT * FROM fields WHERE id = '$id'";
        $fields = mysql_query($fields_query);
        $field = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields); 
        $content .= '<div><label> ' . $field['field'] . ': </label>';       
        $content .= '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $field['id'] . '" value="' . $field['options'] . '" /> ' . $field['labels'] . '</div>';
        return $content;
    }       

}

?>


//Controller
$fields_quesry = "SELECT * FROM fields";
$fields = mysql_query($fields_quesry);

$form = new form;

$form->genQuestion($field['id']);
```

Comment: This is not a crit forum. Try here: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/forum/13-php-coding-help/

Comment: Seems like a sort of template would be a better match for you, given what your current class does. Thats not considering the error in your class(no return in `getQuestionType` ect.).

Comment: consider to uppercase the first letter of a class name and consider camel style function names

Comment: Not a bad start, but improvements can be made. If `$id` is central to the operation of a `form` then consider adding that into the constructor instead of `genQuestion()` (i.e. in the lifetime of the object, you would not wish to use it with a different `$id` without creating another object). If so, you could also do the repeated query in your constructor, so that you only do it once. Next, consider making any methods that you only use internally in the class `protected` so that you know they can be refactored later on if you wish, without disturbing other code.

Comment: As @hek2mgl says, a better (CamelCaseName) is better, since it is a convention, and make it quite specific so you don't get name conflicts with other libraries. If you use a simple name of `Form` then you may have to use namespaces to avoid conflicts (there are sure to be hundreds of identically-named classes available), and that's an extra complication you might prefer to tackle at another time!

Answer (score 2):

The point of OOP is not to just use classes. Is to actually feel object oriented. What does it means?

Procedural code is aimed at making a program as a series of algorithms. OOP code is aimed instead at looking at the program as a series of objects that are filled with (usually) private data that are managed by the object itself.

When you are coding a project *the OOP way* you are not *forced* to use classes. You should use classes when you feel the need to have a bunch of data and to make that data accessible only the way you want.

In your code I don't see that class as an object, but rather a bunch of helper functions linked together by a class that should really not be there.

Comment: oh boy, i have a lot to learn.  I have made some corrections. please let me know if i have made any improvements.